# Unable to delete AKS cluster

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

After the announcement of AKS (Azure's managed Kubernetes service) I decided to try it out. I'm not experienced with Azure (aside from administering Office365 and using Azure AD), so I just copy-pasted commands from the introduction blog post.

Unfortunately, creating a cluster failed with the following error:

`$ az aks create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyManagedCluster --ssh-key-value ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

> Deployment failed. Correlation ID:
>   cbb78191-73a0-4c78-aaed-f991fdae5f4f. unable to create resource group.
>   error: resources.ProvidersClient#Register: Failure responding to
>   request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service
>   returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The
>   client '761da5e6-d1ed-41b4-8cb5-3c60d8ae1243' with object id
>   '761da5e6-d1ed-41b4-8cb5-3c60d8ae1243' does not have authorization to
>   perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/register/action' over scope
>   '/subscriptions/5aedaa24-356a-4b17-98b3-d09129d00f4d'."

However, `az aks list` *does* show a cluster was created. Due to the error I wanted to delete the cluster, but **deletion also fails!**

`$ az aks delete --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name MyManagedCluster`

> Are you sure you want to perform this operation? (y/n): y
>   Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 64fd7054-3f4b-4dd7-99dc-6978233661be. failed
>   to delete resource group: resources.ProvidersClient#Register: Failure
>   responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error:
>   autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403
>   Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client
>   '761da5e6-d1ed-41b4-8cb5-3c60d8ae1243' with object id
>   '761da5e6-d1ed-41b4-8cb5-3c60d8ae1243' does not have authorization to
>   perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/register/action' over scope
>   '/subscriptions/5aedaa24-356a-4b17-98b3-d09129d00f4d'."

I tried deleting from the cli and from the Azure Portal, multiple times. Each time it failed due to apparently insufficient authorization, despite the Portal claiming I'm actually the owner of the cluster.

So, I'm stuck with an unwanted cluster. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use AKS, you are required to register with Microsoft.Compute and Microsoft.Network resource providers. 
You can do that in the subscription blade in Azure portal:
[image]

From Azure cli,

```
az provider register -n Microsoft.Compute
az provider register -n Microsoft.Network
```

Please register above resource providers and delete the AKS resource and retry creating again.

AKS team is working on properly exposing this error message.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea about the existence of those providers. After registering them deletion worked fine.